# FluentValidation with Mediatr and Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container, fluentvalidation, mediatr

I'm trying to use FluentValidation in a WebApi project (not asp.net Core).

I have the following code:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents(UnityContainer container)
    {
        // Register validators
        RegisterValidators(container);

        // Mediatr
        container.RegisterType<IMediator, Mediator>();
        container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssemblies(true, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()), WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces, GetName, GetLifetimeManager);

        container.RegisterInstance<SingleInstanceFactory>(t => container.Resolve(t));
        container.RegisterInstance<MultiInstanceFactory>(t => container.ResolveAll(t));

        // Automapper profiles
        var profileTypes = typeof(BaseProfile).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseProfile)));
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => new MapperConfiguration(x =>
        {
            foreach (var type in profileTypes)
            {
                var profile = (BaseProfile)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                cfg.AddProfile(profile);
            }
        }));

        container.RegisterInstance<IConfigurationProvider>(config);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }        

    static LifetimeManager GetLifetimeManager(Type type)
    {
        return IsNotificationHandler(type) ? new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() : null;
    }

    static string GetName(Type type)
    {
        return IsNotificationHandler(type) ? string.Format("HandlerFor" + type.Name) : string.Empty;
    }

    private static void RegisterValidators(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        var validators = AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        validators.ForEach(validator => container.RegisterType(validator.InterfaceType, validator.ValidatorType));
    }
}
```

I'm scanning the assemblies and registrering the validators, of which there's only one right now, it sits here: (don't mind the weird validations, I'm trying to have it fail)

```
public class Query : IRequest<Result>
    {
        public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class QueryValidator : AbstractValidator<Query>
    {
        public QueryValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(q => q.Id).Empty();
            RuleFor(q => q.Id).Equal(Guid.NewGuid());
        }
    }
```

My Application_start looks like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(container);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);            

        var factory = new UnityValidatorFactory2(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, x => x.ValidatorFactory = factory);
    }
```

And I have the following validatorFactory:

```
public class UnityValidatorFactory2 : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly HttpConfiguration _configuration;

    public UnityValidatorFactory2(HttpConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        var validator = _configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(validatorType) as IValidator;

        return validator;
    }
}
```

Now; when I call the action on the controller, 'CreateInstance' tries to resolve a validatorType of the type:

```
IValidator<Guid>
```

instead of:

```
IValidator<Query>
```

and of course finds nothing, this means that my validations does not run.

Does anyone have an ideas as to why this is? it seems faily straight forward, so I have trouble seeing what goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After having slept on it, I found the answer myself.

I was posting a Guid to my controller instead of the model I was trying to validate (which only contains a guid)

After posting the right model, it now validates correctly.